# How do I grab the first element from this string that looks like an array?

Tags: arrays, excel

In Excel, I have a cell containing a string that looks like this:

`[[1.234,3.21],[2.345,3.21]]`

I want the average of 1.234 and 2.345 in one cell, and the average of 3.21 and 3.21 in the other.

I've never worked with a string that looks like an array from other programming languages before.

How can I achieve what I want with an Excel formula?

Comment: Remove the `[]` then `split` by `,`?

Comment: Trivial in VBA. Trickier (though still quite possible) using just spreadsheet formulas. Which solution are you shooting for?

Comment: @JohnColeman Excel formula

Comment: excel doesn't have "arrays", really. that's just a text string, and you'll have to use to string operations to extract those values. good luck.

Comment: Is the string always exactly like that -- without any embedded spaces?

Comment: @JohnColeman Correct

Comment: So based on your comment to john you are only ever working with a 2X2 array in string form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
=AVERAGE(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"[",""),"]",""),",",REPT(" ",99)),((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*99)+1,99)),--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"[",""),"]",""),",",REPT(" ",99)),((COLUMN(B:B))*99),99)))
```

Then drag across one and down as far as needed

[image]

Comment: The trick is to be working on answers to other questions while someone has Scott distracted!  But to clarify Scott's answer, Copying to the right will just grab the next element in the array for averaging.  If you copy down it starts looking at the next supplied array in string format.

Comment: I remember that one time they took Scott's computer away. Only day I got over 20 points XD

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression for this.
Since u did not ask in a specific programming language, this is all I can answer.

Comment: How would I do this with an Excel formula?

Comment: @ZenelShabani It was tagged Excel.  Unless you know that regular expressions can be used in Excel I don't see how this answers the question.  And if they can be used, it would be nice if you explained how to use them to answer the question.

Comment: Somehow missid that, not familiar with Exel, Sorry